# MSBuild - How to copy files that are outside the Project directory

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, copy, csproj

I am new to MSBuild and I am trying to copy a file from one folder on my source control to the project directory. Below is the code:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MySourceFiles Include="C:\my_clearcase_view\Demo_Folder\demo.jar" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\demo.jar" />
</Target>
```

This code works with the absolute path for the 'demo.jar' file. And the folder structure looks like this:

```
C:\my_clearcase_view\
             - DemoFolder (Source)
             - my_project (Destination, which is $(MSBuildProjectDirectory))
```

Assuming that the source path will never change, how can I get the relative path for the source file that is above my project in folder hierarchy? I can only get to the root of the project directory by using $(MSBuildDirectory). Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can just do;

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MySourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Demo_Folder\demo.jar" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory. But that doesn't work. I want to go up the hierarchy of my $MSBuildProjectDirectory. This gives me the path - "C:\my_clearcase_view\my_project\..\Demo\demo.jar" which throws a 'could not find path' error.

Comment: That error has a slightly different path to the example in your question - it has "\Demo\" instead of "\Demo_Folder\". Is that your problem? The ".." directory just means "parent of this directory", so it ought to work if you want to go one (or more) levels up.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rory's answer, I tried different combinations and finally got it.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <MySourceFiles Include="..\Demo_Folder\demo.jar" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Thanks for the pointer Rory.